# How can I sort a list in n log n with a storage of O(1) and non recursively?

Tags: java, sorting, iteration

I need to sort a list from smallest to greatest made on the mod of k. I am only able to use to do this in a purely iterative way, with nothing that is recursive. Basically the only thing I get is:

```
public static void sortMod(int [] a, int k)
```

How can I do this with only n log n runtime and O(1) space and without creating any new arrays?

Answer (score 0):

the .sort() method of the Array class can have a special argument which is the comparison function but I'm not sure it has the complexity you're looking for.
[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_sorts) is a list of algorithms with their complexities so you can try to implement one with you own comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

Timsort is a hybrid of insertion sort and (non-recursive) merging.  It is `O(NlogN)` worst case and `O(N)` in the best case, and requires no auxiliary storage.

You should be able to adapt it to your problem involving ordering modulo K.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/timsort/ - includes implementations in 4 languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterative in-place versions of `O(N * log(N))` sorting algorithms.
For example:

- [Iterative Merge Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-merge-sort/)
- [Iterative Quick Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-quick-sort/)
- [Iterative HeapSort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-heap-sort/)

But I'm not sure about `O(1)` space complexity.

I think it would be at least `O(log(n))` space complexity. Or use `O(N ^ 2)` sorting algorithms where `O(1)` space complexity.